# Makefile : How to build this conditional rule?

Tags: makefile

I have a folder with several sub-projects in forms of subfolders with all a makefile in them. 
The folders are called with the following semantic : `X_Y` where `X` is a type of folder (three letters, e.g `tex`, `rmd`, `dat`,...) and `Y` is just a unique identifier, made of letters and numbers (e.g `mymodel2`), making the list of folders look like :

```
mod_x1
mod_x2
tex_x3
rmd_x4
```

For each folder, i want the call `make Y` to be extended to `make -C X_Y`. Since the second part of the folder names are unique identifiers, there should be no ambiguity. For exemple, if only the 4 exemple folders exists,

- `make x1` -> `make -C mod_x1/`
- `make x2` -> `make -C mod_x2/`
- `make x3` -> `make -C tex_x3/`
- `make x4` -> `make -C rmd_x4/`
- `make x5` should produce an error.

How can i do that ? Note that, for other folder and files, there are other rules in the makefile. this shouldbe like a "default rule if nothing else apply"

Answer (score 0):

It takes a fair bit of infrastructure to get a plain `make` to do exactly everything that you want, especially if the list of actual subdirectories which need aliases are not know, and especially if you don't already have helper rules for subdirectories.

However in a BSD Make it's easy as all that infrastructure is provided for you.  Here's an example of creating targets with simple target names based on the full subdirectory names for BSD Make (with the main part being the definition of `${SUBDIR}` and the last little `.for` loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
#
# provide aliases for subdirectory targets
#
SUBDIR= mod_x1 mod_x2 tex_x3 rmd_x4

.include <bsd.own.mk>

.if !defined(MAKEDIRTARGET)
# Only NetBSD has MAKEDIRTARGET by default...
MAKEDIRTARGETENV?=
MAKEDIRTARGET=\
    @_makedirtarget() { \
        dir="$$1"; shift; \
        target="$$1"; shift; \
        case "$${dir}" in \
        /*) this="$${dir}/"; \
            real="$${dir}" ;; \
        .)  this="${_THISDIR_}"; \
            real="${.CURDIR}" ;; \
        *)  this="${_THISDIR_}$${dir}/"; \
            real="${.CURDIR}/$${dir}" ;; \
        esac; \
        show=$${this:-.}; \
        echo "$${target} ===> $${show%/}$${1:+  (with: $$@)}"; \
        cd "$${real}" \
        && ${MAKEDIRTARGETENV} ${MAKE} _THISDIR_="$${this}" "$$@" $${target}; \
    }; \
    _makedirtarget
.endif

.for dir in ${SUBDIR}
${dir:C/^.*_//}: ${dir} .PHONY
    ${MAKEDIRTARGET} ${dir} all
.endfor

.include <bsd.subdir.mk>
```

I'll leave translating this to your favourite `make` as an exercise for the reader.